# Calling own custom methods through Odoo API using xmlrpc

Tags: api, odoo

I add a function on res_partner.py called "testing".
I am using xmlrpc to calling the methods

> $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'testing', array(array(intval($id)));

I got this error

> 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'testing'

Can anyone help me to figure out please ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `testing` method?
Its signature may not match what the system is expecting.

Comment: Use @api.model decorator on your testing method

Answer (score 0):

> $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'read',
>   array(array(intval($id)));

That is execute Method has not testing attribute.

you can use the attribute as **read , write**

i hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer before it helped me:
you can check the [calling methods](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html#calling-methods) part in the documentation. in the right tab you can see how to call as an example the method: check_access_rights in the res.partner model.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this problem, and in my case was a stupid error, I guess you have been experienced something similar.

The message

> 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'testing'

tells that you have not created any method named `testing` in the `res.partner` model of your database.

So you must check if you have restarted the Odoo service (to reload Python code), if you have installed the module which introduces that method (this one was my error), if you are calling the database where you installed this module, if you added your Python file to your `__init__.py`, etc... There could be a lot of errors which cause this problem, **but it is not about the XMLRPC call**.

You can call customized methods from XMLRPC with no problem.